# Does java maven spring really work with google app engine

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, gwt-maven-plugin

I created a project testprojectapp using maven

mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.18 -Dapplication-id=testprojectapp -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes:

my pom.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.testprojectapp.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>testprojectapp</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.1.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.18</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.18</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.18</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just localhost -->
                    <!-- address>0.0.0.0</address>
                    <port>8080</port -->
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remove debugger
                         like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
                    <!-- jvmFlags>
                      <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        </pluginManagement>
            </build>
</project>
```

Then i try to upload using mvn appengine:update

```
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Updating Application
[INFO] 
[INFO] Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.638 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-18T12:59:03-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/185M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.18:update (default-cli) on project testprojectapp: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.18:update failed. NoSuchElementException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I have another spring based project that works well on local but get the same error while trying to upload the project.  I saw similar threads without any answers.  Can google or an expert please confirm if this kind of project (JAVA + MAVEN3.25 + SPRING 4 + Spring Security) is really possible on google apps or should I find another cloud platform.  For all I know its just a trick by google to get us create trial accounts.  Please help if there is anything wrong that i am doing here.

Below is my appengine-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>projectid</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

------------------UPDATE-------------
Alright maven and google app experts this one is for you guys.  I included the pom.xml from this site 
http://java-in-cloud.blogspot.com/2013/11/java-maven-gae-spring-and-vaadin-all.html
and I was able to build successfully google gave me the code and all.  Below is my new pom.xml.  It will be wonderful if someone could point out what I was missing or did wrong.  Never worked on maven.
In the meantime I will find out if this works with the app I have and update what happens later.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.testprojectapp.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>testprojectapp</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.2.5</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <Xlint>warning</Xlint>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.18</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.18</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.18</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    </project>
```

Alright so I was able to upload my testapp test it and it works.  Guess I'll have to go through maven so this doesn't happen again.

Any pointers will be helpful
Thank you

Comment: do you have a projectID setup? did you create it beforehand? normally that's what these errors link to

Comment: Yes I did set up a project id from Google dev console and used that to create the project.  -Dapplication-id=projectid  is that the right way?? I can see the project on my google console. I created the project on dev console on Google first and then the maven on my local using the generated project Id

Comment: yes, but is it also in the relevant files? (appengine-web.xml in java, app.yaml in python)

Comment: I'll check that and update. Don't have access to the project right now. Love the Google workflow and datastores I hope I can get this working. I'll post my appengine-web.xml

Comment: Yes the project id is my appengine-web.xml